allure reports not running, although allure is installed - allure command not found
I am using Nightwatch js, and have allure installed, and have been using reports successfully. However, something has changed, and now I get the following error:
$ allure generate ./allure-results --clean && allure open 
bash: allure: command not found

I have allure-report folder and allure-results folder. Results folder holds up to date records, but nothing is being written to report folder.
Package.json looks correct - contains references to allure:
{
    "name": "automation-poc",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --retries 1",
        "cleanConfigFiles": "del 'config/*.conf.js'",
        "cleanReports": "del 'reports/*'"
    },
    "author": "Alex",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "allure-commandline": "^2.29.0",
        "chromedriver": "^94.0.0",
        "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
        "del": "^4.1.1",
        "del-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "nightwatch": "^2.2.3",
        "nightwatch-allure": "^1.2.0",
        "selenium-server": "^3.141.59",
        "uuid": "^10.0.0",
        "yargs": "^15.3.1"
    }
}

I've run various commands:
npm install allure-commandline
npm install nightwatch-allure
allure generate ./allure-results --clean && allure open
allure --version
npm install -g allure-commandline
npm install -g nightwatch-allure
I've made sure there's an entry in System Variables for the location of \node_modules\allure-commandline\bin
I've tried deleting the node_modules folder and running npm install again

I have the same problem. And the decision is the same:
npm root -g 

And you have a path:
C:\Users\<YourName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
You need to add it to "Path" in the System variable:
C:\Users\<YourName>\AppData\Roaming\npm
(without node_modules)
Restart your machine and will be happy ^)

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

After much investigation, it turns out my code was all fine - the allure_commandline folder had been removed from my machine. Reinstalled it, added the system variable, and it worked - eureka!
